# NULL check in WHERE query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to put this check in my oracle statement

```
  AND   country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY')
```

but I want to put a case when `case.xsa_region` is not null only then this statement should e evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:

```
and (
  case.xsa_region is null or
  (
    case.xsa_region is not null
    and country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY')
  )
)
```

> but I want to put a case when case.xsa_region is not null only then this statement should [b]e evaluated.

The condition `case.xsa_region is not null` *ANDed* to the statement `country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN (...)` that you want to add will make sure that that statement will be evaluated if the `xsa_region` is not null.

But `xsa_region` can be null. And your statement has an `and` keyword in the beginning, implying that your statement will be added to an existing *where* clause. So that your whole *where* clause can be evaluated to true when `xsa_region` is null, we add `xsa_region is null` *ORed* to the two conditions we *ANDed* earlier.

Answer (score 0):

use Boolean condition it will also work

```
where  (country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY')   
and country.xsa_region is not null)
```

Comment: You have changed the criteria, he stated that only if `xsa_region` is not null should this be evaluated, you have made it into a requirement that it is non-null, which is different.

Comment: country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY') filters out null value also.. I dont want null value to be filtered out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in what scenario you want to do this since you didn't mentioned about this. But you can do :

```
WHERE (xsa_region IS NOT NULL AND 
       country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY')
      )
```

Comment: You have changed the criteria, he stated that only if `xsa_region` is not null should this be evaluated, you have made it into a requirement that it is non-null, which is different.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. . . Assumed `xsa_region` want to be `X_GSA_REGION`.

Comment: country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY') this statement filters out records which are having null value.. I dont want null values to be filtered out

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate is a *implication*

```
(.xsa_region is not null )  - - > (X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY') )
```

In words if the XSA region is not null than the GSA region must not be in the list.

The transformation rule for `A --> B`  is  `NOT (A) OR B`

i.e. your predicate is (list simplified)

```
not (XSA_REGION is NOT NULL) OR GSA_REGION not in ('DUMMY');
```

which can be rewritten to

(XSA_REGION is NULL) OR GSA_REGION not in ('DUMMY');

Example

```
select * from tab;        

        ID XSA_REGION GSA_REGION
---------- ---------- ----------
         1            DUMMY      
         2            X          
         3 X          DUMMY      
         4 X          X        

select * from tab
where GSA_REGION not in ('DUMMY');

       ID XSA_REGION GSA_REGION
---------- ---------- ----------
         2            X          
         4 X          X  


--  A --> B  means NOT (A)  OR B
select * from tab
where 
not (XSA_REGION is NOT NULL) OR GSA_REGION not in ('DUMMY');

        ID XSA_REGION GSA_REGION
---------- ---------- ----------
         1            DUMMY      
         2            X          
         4 X          X
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `nvl` with an irrelevant argument as :

```
AND nvl(country.X_GSA_REGION,'xYzDt') NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY')
```

this case doesn't exclude the null values for `country.X_GSA_REGION` column.

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4194/64)

Comment: Sending the table's value through a function is a good way to completely kill any optimization through indexes this table might have had. So if this is one constraint out of many and other indices will be used anyway it's acceptable,  otherwise it's an invitation for a full table scan that the other answers avoid.

Comment: @nvoigt yes, you're right, but in Oracle(for the recent versions) a functional index may be created on `nvl(country.X_GSA_REGION,'xYzDt')` considering that as a column.

Comment: While it can be done, it would be an extra overhead the other answers avoid. It certainly works and in some situations will not be a drawback, but the other answers work in all situations without that extra, so all else being equal, it might be better to use one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition with existing condition and enclose it in bracket

`AND   (case.xsa_region is not null and country.X_GSA_REGION NOT IN ('Russia','Dummy', 'Other', 'DUMMY'))`